# Elastislide slider skip many li when sliding (vertical carousel)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was styling Elastislide  and I noticed it skip  many li or reviews in my case when I slide ???

I added numbers to the title  it will skip from 3 to  8

4 5 6 7 will not be showing

Here an example

https://jsfiddle.net/35q41d6q/

```
<div class="product_rating">
    <div class="top_slider">
        <span class="stamped-reviews-rating">
            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
            <span class="slider_date">2017/5/32</span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <p class="slider_title">Compact, Portable & Functional1</p>
    <img class="slider_images" width="72" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/...">
    <span class="slider_review">Slim bottle that fits perfectly in my
        handbag. Bought the A6 memobottle with the collapsible funnel 
        for easy pouring of water. Purchase was value for money.</span>
    <p class="slider_user_name">Brian A</p>
</div>
```

how can I fix this issue

Comment: look like you been messing up with the css

Comment: @Muhammad Omer Aslam  I changed the width of  li  so I can add reviews info since the slider has images only.

Comment: added an answer see if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work that way, the way you are trying to change it. Above all this repo seems to be abandoned since there are issues from 2015 which are not addressed even once by the repo owner.

Anyway, coming to changing it the way you are trying to do it, you first need to understand what the script is actually doing. If you have to add your custom HTML inside the `li` and use the slider you need to look into how it assigns the `max-width` and `width`, rather than trying to force to override it inside the css.

Looking into `jquery.elastislide.js` what it is doing is that it assign's the `max-width` to the items/lis in the [**`_setItemSize()`**](https://github.com/codrops/Elastislide/blob/master/js/jquery.elastislide.js#L414) function where it uses `imgSize` object's property `width` to assign the `max-width` css property to the item.

```
this.$items.css({
    'width': w + '%',
    'max-width': this.imgSize.width,
    'max-height': this.imgSize.height
});
```

Now if you backtrack you will find that this `imgSize` object is actually the saved original image sizes(`width`, `height`) which is inside the [**`_layout()`**](https://github.com/codrops/Elastislide/blob/master/js/jquery.elastislide.js#L352) function

```
var $img = this.$items.find('img:first');
this.imgSize = {
    width: $img.outerWidth(true),
    height: $img.outerHeight(true)
};
```

which when backtracked is called inside the [**`init()`**](https://github.com/codrops/Elastislide/blob/master/js/jquery.elastislide.js#L282) function when all the images are loaded.

This reveals that the li size will always depend on the first image size inside the first li, as it uses `$img.outerWidth(true),` with `true` which means it will get the current computed outer width (including padding, border, and optionally margin) for the first element in the set of matched elements, but it will assign the same dimensions as image inside it and that too the first inside the first `li` `var $img = this.$items.find('img:first');`. as it does gets all li and the first image inside them but uses only the first li's image dimensions to assign to all the items/lis.

Now you are totally doing it differently you are adding nested HTML inside the anchor and the image there is a smaller size so actually, you are forcing the layout to show your desired width but the plugin javascript uses the same logic as defined above to calculate the dimensions and hence slide the number of lis.

You have 2 options

- Change the logic in the source (i won't go for that as it would require a lot of time maybe maybe not.)
- Fool the slider

How to fool the slider is that you can trick the slider by providing a blank image with `display:none` with the actual dimensions that you want the tiles of the sliders or `li` to be and it will automatically get the dimensions and move and calculate the slider tiles accordingly.

I have created and uploaded a blank image [**`BLANK.GIF`**](https://omaraslam.com/blank.png) so you can download an use it I created it `290x161` as per your CSS settings. You can modify it if you want to change the tile's size and adjust accordingly.

See a demo below I have added a blank image in the first li only and now all of your slides will be sliding correctly. Run demo in Full Mode

Hope this helps, that is all I can do the rest you should do by your self if you want to skip the slides or do something else you should dig into the code first then implement.

```js
$('#carousel').elastislide({
  orientation: 'horizontal',

  // sliding speed
  speed: 1000,

  // sliding easing
  easing: 'ease-in-out',

  // the minimum number of items to show.
  // when we resize the window, this will make sure minItems are always shown
  // (unless of course minItems is higher than the total number of elements)
  minItems: 5,

  // index of the current item (left most item of the carousel)
  start: 0,
});
```

```css
.slider_container {
  /* max-width: 1250px; */
  font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #333;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

#carousel {
  max-height: 145px !important;
}

#carousel li {
  max-width: 290px !important;
  max-height: 161px !important;
}

#carousel .fa-star {
  font-size: 15px;
}

#carousel .slider_review {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: normal !important;
  color: #2b2b2b;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 87px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-right: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: left;
}

#carousel .slider_title {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  font-size: 13px;
  width: auto;
  line-height: 21px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

#carousel .slider_user_name {
  margin-top: 6px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  top: -12px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

#carousel a {
  color: #555;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#carousel .top_slider {
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
}

#carousel .slider_date {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 15px;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.slider_images {
  display: inline-block !important;
  float: left;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
  border: 1px solid #ddd !important;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: white;
}

.slider_upper_section {
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.slider_upper_stars {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.slider_upper_title {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://omaraslam.com/modernizr.js"></script>
<link href="https://areviewsapp.com/css/slider/elastislide.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://omaraslam.com/elastislide.js"></script>

<div class="slider_container demo-1">
  <div class="slider_upper_section">
    <span class="slider_upper_title">What our customers have to say...</span>
    <span class="slider_upper_stars">
                         <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <span >120 Reviews</span>

    </span>
  </div>

  <!-- Elastislide Carousel -->
  <ul id="carousel" class="elastislide-list">
    <li>
      <img src="https://omaraslam.com/blank.png" style="display:none">
      <a href="#">
        <div>
          <div class="product_rating">
            <div class="top_slider">
              <span class="stamped-reviews-rating">
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <span class="slider_date">2017/5/32</span>
              </span>
            </div>
            <p class="slider_title">Compact, Portable & Functional1</p>
            <img class="slider_images" width="72" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/stamped.io/uploads/productImages/thumb/28_8586632067.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJZP6NJTFV3IFIHLQ&Expires=2147472000&Signature=SsdO7t34Kfp3sDm7bzW4%2BfM48BM%3D">
            <span class="slider_review">Slim bottle that fits perfectly in my handbag. Bought the A6 memobottle with the collapsible funnel for easy pouring of water. Purchase was value for money.</span>
            <p class="slider_user_name">Brian A</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div>
          <div class="product_rating">
            <div class="top_slider">
              <span class="stamped-reviews-rating">
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <span class="slider_date">2017/5/32</span>
              </span>
            </div>
            <p class="slider_title">Compact, Portable & Functional2</p>
            <img class="slider_images" width="72" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/stamped.io/uploads/productImages/thumb/28_8586632067.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJZP6NJTFV3IFIHLQ&Expires=2147472000&Signature=SsdO7t34Kfp3sDm7bzW4%2BfM48BM%3D">
            <span class="slider_review">Slim bottle that fits perfectly in my handbag. Bought the A6 memobottle with the collapsible funnel for easy pouring of water. Purchase was value for money.</span>
            <p class="slider_user_name">Brian A</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div>
          <div class="product_rating">
            <div class="top_slider">
              <span class="stamped-reviews-rating">
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <span class="slider_date">2017/5/32</span>
              </span>
            </div>
            <p class="slider_title">Compact, Portable & Functional3</p>
            <img class="slider_images" width="72" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/stamped.io/uploads/productImages/thumb/28_8586632067.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJZP6NJTFV3IFIHLQ&Expires=2147472000&Signature=SsdO7t34Kfp3sDm7bzW4%2BfM48BM%3D">
            <span class="slider_review">Slim bottle that fits perfectly in my handbag. Bought the A6 memobottle with the collapsible funnel for easy pouring of water. Purchase was value for money.</span>
            <p class="slider_user_name">Brian A</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div>
          <div class="product_rating">
            <div class="top_slider">
              <span class="stamped-reviews-rating">
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <span class="slider_date">2017/5/32</span>
              </span>
            </div>
            <p class="slider_title">Compact, Portable & Functional4</p>
            <img class="slider_images" width="72" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/stamped.io/uploads/productImages/thumb/28_8586632067.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJZP6NJTFV3IFIHLQ&Expires=2147472000&Signature=SsdO7t34Kfp3sDm7bzW4%2BfM48BM%3D">
            <span class="slider_review">Slim bottle that fits perfectly in my handbag. Bought the A6 memobottle with the collapsible funnel for easy pouring of water. Purchase was value for money.</span>
            <p class="slider_user_name">Brian A</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div>
          <div class="product_rating">
            <div class="top_slider">
              <span class="stamped-reviews-rating">
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <span class="slider_date">2017/5/32</span>
              </span>
            </div>
            <p class="slider_title">Compact, Portable & Functional5</p>
            <img class="slider_images" width="72" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/stamped.io/uploads/productImages/thumb/28_8586632067.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJZP6NJTFV3IFIHLQ&Expires=2147472000&Signature=SsdO7t34Kfp3sDm7bzW4%2BfM48BM%3D">
            <span class="slider_review">Slim bottle that fits perfectly in my handbag. Bought the A6 memobottle with the collapsible funnel for easy pouring of water. Purchase was value for money.</span>
            <p class="slider_user_name">Brian A</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div>
          <div class="product_rating">
            <div class="top_slider">
              <span class="stamped-reviews-rating">
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <span class="slider_date">2017/5/32</span>
              </span>
            </div>
            <p class="slider_title">Compact, Portable & Functional6</p>
            <img class="slider_images" width="72" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/stamped.io/uploads/productImages/thumb/28_8586632067.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJZP6NJTFV3IFIHLQ&Expires=2147472000&Signature=SsdO7t34Kfp3sDm7bzW4%2BfM48BM%3D">
            <span class="slider_review">Slim bottle that fits perfectly in my handbag. Bought the A6 memobottle with the collapsible funnel for easy pouring of water. Purchase was value for money.</span>
            <p class="slider_user_name">Brian A</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div>
          <div class="product_rating">
            <div class="top_slider">
              <span class="stamped-reviews-rating">
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <span class="slider_date">2017/5/32</span>
              </span>
            </div>
            <p class="slider_title">Compact, Portable & Functional7</p>
            <img class="slider_images" width="72" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/stamped.io/uploads/productImages/thumb/28_8586632067.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJZP6NJTFV3IFIHLQ&Expires=2147472000&Signature=SsdO7t34Kfp3sDm7bzW4%2BfM48BM%3D">
            <span class="slider_review">Slim bottle that fits perfectly in my handbag. Bought the A6 memobottle with the collapsible funnel for easy pouring of water. Purchase was value for money.</span>
            <p class="slider_user_name">Brian A</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div>
          <div class="product_rating">
            <div class="top_slider">
              <span class="stamped-reviews-rating">
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <span class="slider_date">2017/5/32</span>
              </span>
            </div>
            <p class="slider_title">Compact, Portable & Functional8</p>
            <img class="slider_images" width="72" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/stamped.io/uploads/productImages/thumb/28_8586632067.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJZP6NJTFV3IFIHLQ&Expires=2147472000&Signature=SsdO7t34Kfp3sDm7bzW4%2BfM48BM%3D">
            <span class="slider_review">Slim bottle that fits perfectly in my handbag. Bought the A6 memobottle with the collapsible funnel for easy pouring of water. Purchase was value for money.</span>
            <p class="slider_user_name">Brian A</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div>
          <div class="product_rating">
            <div class="top_slider">
              <span class="stamped-reviews-rating">
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <span class="slider_date">2017/5/32</span>
              </span>
            </div>
            <p class="slider_title">Compact, Portable & Functional9</p>
            <img class="slider_images" width="72" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/stamped.io/uploads/productImages/thumb/28_8586632067.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJZP6NJTFV3IFIHLQ&Expires=2147472000&Signature=SsdO7t34Kfp3sDm7bzW4%2BfM48BM%3D">
            <span class="slider_review">Slim bottle that fits perfectly in my handbag. Bought the A6 memobottle with the collapsible funnel for easy pouring of water. Purchase was value for money.</span>
            <p class="slider_user_name">Brian A</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div>
          <div class="product_rating">
            <div class="top_slider">
              <span class="stamped-reviews-rating">
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <span class="slider_date">2017/5/32</span>
              </span>
            </div>
            <p class="slider_title">Compact, Portable & Functional10</p>
            <img class="slider_images" width="72" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/stamped.io/uploads/productImages/thumb/28_8586632067.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJZP6NJTFV3IFIHLQ&Expires=2147472000&Signature=SsdO7t34Kfp3sDm7bzW4%2BfM48BM%3D">
            <span class="slider_review">Slim bottle that fits perfectly in my handbag. Bought the A6 memobottle with the collapsible funnel for easy pouring of water. Purchase was value for money.</span>
            <p class="slider_user_name">Brian A</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div>
          <div class="product_rating">
            <div class="top_slider">
              <span class="stamped-reviews-rating">
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <span class="slider_date">2017/5/32</span>
              </span>
            </div>
            <p class="slider_title">Compact, Portable & Functional11</p>
            <img class="slider_images" width="72" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/stamped.io/uploads/productImages/thumb/28_8586632067.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJZP6NJTFV3IFIHLQ&Expires=2147472000&Signature=SsdO7t34Kfp3sDm7bzW4%2BfM48BM%3D">
            <span class="slider_review">Slim bottle that fits perfectly in my handbag. Bought the A6 memobottle with the collapsible funnel for easy pouring of water. Purchase was value for money.</span>
            <p class="slider_user_name">Brian A</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div>
          <div class="product_rating">
            <div class="top_slider">
              <span class="stamped-reviews-rating">
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <span class="slider_date">2017/5/32</span>
              </span>
            </div>
            <p class="slider_title">Compact, Portable & Functional12</p>
            <img class="slider_images" width="72" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/stamped.io/uploads/productImages/thumb/28_8586632067.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJZP6NJTFV3IFIHLQ&Expires=2147472000&Signature=SsdO7t34Kfp3sDm7bzW4%2BfM48BM%3D">
            <span class="slider_review">Slim bottle that fits perfectly in my handbag. Bought the A6 memobottle with the collapsible funnel for easy pouring of water. Purchase was value for money.</span>
            <p class="slider_user_name">Brian A</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div>
          <div class="product_rating">
            <div class="top_slider">
              <span class="stamped-reviews-rating">
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <span class="slider_date">2017/5/32</span>
              </span>
            </div>
            <p class="slider_title">Compact, Portable & Functional13</p>
            <img class="slider_images" width="72" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/stamped.io/uploads/productImages/thumb/28_8586632067.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJZP6NJTFV3IFIHLQ&Expires=2147472000&Signature=SsdO7t34Kfp3sDm7bzW4%2BfM48BM%3D">
            <span class="slider_review">Slim bottle that fits perfectly in my handbag. Bought the A6 memobottle with the collapsible funnel for easy pouring of water. Purchase was value for money.</span>
            <p class="slider_user_name">Brian A</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div>
          <div class="product_rating">
            <div class="top_slider">
              <span class="stamped-reviews-rating">
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <span class="slider_date">2017/5/32</span>
              </span>
            </div>
            <p class="slider_title">Compact, Portable & Functional14</p>
            <img class="slider_images" width="72" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/stamped.io/uploads/productImages/thumb/28_8586632067.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJZP6NJTFV3IFIHLQ&Expires=2147472000&Signature=SsdO7t34Kfp3sDm7bzW4%2BfM48BM%3D">
            <span class="slider_review">Slim bottle that fits perfectly in my handbag. Bought the A6 memobottle with the collapsible funnel for easy pouring of water. Purchase was value for money.</span>
            <p class="slider_user_name">Brian A</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div>
          <div class="product_rating">
            <div class="top_slider">
              <span class="stamped-reviews-rating">
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <span class="slider_date">2017/5/32</span>
              </span>
            </div>
            <p class="slider_title">Compact, Portable & Functional15</p>
            <img class="slider_images" width="72" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/stamped.io/uploads/productImages/thumb/28_8586632067.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJZP6NJTFV3IFIHLQ&Expires=2147472000&Signature=SsdO7t34Kfp3sDm7bzW4%2BfM48BM%3D">
            <span class="slider_review">Slim bottle that fits perfectly in my handbag. Bought the A6 memobottle with the collapsible funnel for easy pouring of water. Purchase was value for money.</span>
            <p class="slider_user_name">Brian A</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div>
          <div class="product_rating">
            <div class="top_slider">
              <span class="stamped-reviews-rating">
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <span class="slider_date">2017/5/32</span>
              </span>
            </div>
            <p class="slider_title">Compact, Portable & Functional16</p>
            <img class="slider_images" width="72" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/stamped.io/uploads/productImages/thumb/28_8586632067.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJZP6NJTFV3IFIHLQ&Expires=2147472000&Signature=SsdO7t34Kfp3sDm7bzW4%2BfM48BM%3D">
            <span class="slider_review">Slim bottle that fits perfectly in my handbag. Bought the A6 memobottle with the collapsible funnel for easy pouring of water. Purchase was value for money.</span>
            <p class="slider_user_name">Brian A</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div>
          <div class="product_rating">
            <div class="top_slider">
              <span class="stamped-reviews-rating">
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <span class="slider_date">2017/5/32</span>
              </span>
            </div>
            <p class="slider_title">Compact, Portable & Functional17</p>
            <img class="slider_images" width="72" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/stamped.io/uploads/productImages/thumb/28_8586632067.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJZP6NJTFV3IFIHLQ&Expires=2147472000&Signature=SsdO7t34Kfp3sDm7bzW4%2BfM48BM%3D">
            <span class="slider_review">Slim bottle that fits perfectly in my handbag. Bought the A6 memobottle with the collapsible funnel for easy pouring of water. Purchase was value for money.</span>
            <p class="slider_user_name">Brian A</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div>
          <div class="product_rating">
            <div class="top_slider">
              <span class="stamped-reviews-rating">
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <span class="slider_date">2017/5/32</span>
              </span>
            </div>
            <p class="slider_title">Compact, Portable & Functional18</p>
            <img class="slider_images" width="72" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/stamped.io/uploads/productImages/thumb/28_8586632067.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJZP6NJTFV3IFIHLQ&Expires=2147472000&Signature=SsdO7t34Kfp3sDm7bzW4%2BfM48BM%3D">
            <span class="slider_review">Slim bottle that fits perfectly in my handbag. Bought the A6 memobottle with the collapsible funnel for easy pouring of water. Purchase was value for money.</span>
            <p class="slider_user_name">Brian A</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>

  </ul>
  <!-- End Elastislide Carousel -->
</div>
```

Comment: That was cool reply from you, and you solved is completely. I noticed the script take image this.$items.find('img:first');  in this code an actuate the width  therefor I added  fixed width like 219  but it didn't work on all screens it will skip one slides sometimes  but in your way its fixed completely. Thank you Muhammad  I wish you the best ^^.